# Laravel logging gets timeout if the logstash service is down

Tags: laravel, logging, logstash

I have a Laravel application that sends log data to Logstash on an AWS EC2 instance. Recently, the EC2 instance went down, and I noticed that the Laravel application started prompting timeouts when I tried to log and it affects the whole application. Is there a way to configure Laravel or Logstash to handle timeouts or connection failures, or do I need to handle this in my log shipping solution?

```
Failed connecting to tcp://XX.XXX.XX.XX:5044 (111: Connection refused)
```

how can i handle that timeout ?

Comment: What happens when it times out? Usually Laravel would use a failsafe logger (which you can configure at `config/logging.php` under the failsafe key). This might be in the syslog

Comment: thanks for your reply @apokryfos, how can i add that exactly ? 
when it timesout it gives this error `Failed connecting to tcp://XX.XXX.XX.XX:5044 (111: Connection refused)
`

Comment: Sorry not failsafe. It uses the configured `emergency` logger as a fallback logger. By default that logs to a file (storage/logs/laravel.log) but you should be able to change it to something else that would not fail.